# Keras Classification Training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, keras

I am try to train a simple model following (http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-03-NN-Manifolds-Topology/) to understand neural networks better but my model is unable to learn simple curves to segment the data. My loss keeps decreasing but not validation. Even if I make my model more complex its validation loss becomes constant very quickly(at 0.029) and the graph looks like

[image]

I dont understand why a multi layer can't learn the simple up curve after x=4? Would love some help and insights. Ideally this should work with one-two layers as the function it is learning is not very complex.

Here is my basic code:

```
NB_EPOCH = 300


def prepare_data(n_points=256):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n_points)
    shift1 = 0.8
    shift2 = -0.8

    y1 = np.cos(x*1.2)+shift1
    y2 = np.cos(x*1.2)+shift2

    features1 = zip(x, y1)
    features2 = zip(x, y2)

    labels1 = np.zeros((n_points,))
    labels2 = np.ones((n_points,))

    return np.concatenate([features1, features2]), np.concatenate([labels1, labels2])


def create_model():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(2,)))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(2,)))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(2,)))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(4))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(2))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model


if __name__ == "__main__":
    features, labels = prepare_data()
    f_len = features.shape[0]

    labels = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, 2)
    model = create_model()
    print(model.summary())

    model.fit(features, labels, nb_epoch=NB_EPOCH,batch_size=8,validation_split=0.2)

    reshaped_features = features.reshape(features.shape[0], 2)



    fig = plt.figure(1)


    ax = Axes3D(fig) #fig.add_subplot(311, projection='3d')
    ax.plot(features[:f_len/2,0], np.zeros(f_len/2), features[:f_len/2, 1])
    ax.plot(features[f_len/2:,0], np.zeros(f_len/2), features[f_len/2:, 1])

    # ###########################################
    # Separation curve
    # ###########################################
    x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 50), np.linspace(-1, 1, 36))
    input = []

    for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
        for i in range(len(_x)):
            input.append((_x[i], _y[i]))

    input = np.asarray(input)
    classes = model.predict(input)

    first_class_x = []
    first_class_y = []
    second_class_x = []
    second_class_y = []

    for i in range(len(classes)):
        if classes[i][0] > 0.5:
            first_class_x.append(input[i][0])
            first_class_y.append(input[i][1])
        else:
            second_class_x.append(input[i][0])
            second_class_y.append(input[i][1])

    ax.scatter(first_class_x, np.zeros(len(first_class_x)),
               first_class_y, c='r')

    ax.scatter(second_class_x, np.zeros(len(second_class_x)),
               second_class_y, c='y')

    plt.show()
```

Comment: No this is not duplication. My training loss is decreasing. My question is specific to my model complexity being able to learn the required non linear decision boundaries.

Comment: The code you posted is not reproducible. I tried running it to understand the problem better, but it returns multiple errors in many places, so I gave up. This also makes the question not very clear. It seems to be a duplicate of the canonical question we have, so I'm voting to close this as a duplicate. If it is not, please make sure to describe the problem in greater detail (why it is not a duplicate?) and provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear why you're enforcing that the class division occur at $0.5$. Try computing the curve at a different threshold. Specifically, double check the AUC of your predictions.

The linear descent is suspicious however. Calculate the AUC on two intervals $[0,2]$ and $[2,6]$, to see if something is going wrong. Most likely, it's your failure to normalize your data, so try that first. I'm guessing the first layer of hyperbolic tangents gets immediately saturated when $x>4$.